# How include Recipients to django-postman

Tags: django

in django postmon, when sending a message, an empty recipient field, how to auto-detect the recipient by ID, if the message is sent from the recipient's profile page? thank

Answer (score 1):

You can access `user model` in `views`. AND you can do it like :-

**views.py**

```
def your_view(request,user_id):
    name = get_object_or_404(User,user_is=user_id)
    model_contains_recipent_field = model_name.objects.get(user=user_id)
    recipent_form = RecipentForm(model_contains_recipent_field=request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if recipent_form.is_valid():
            recipent_form.instance.recipent_by = request.user

    context = {'name':name,'model_contains_recipent_field':model_contains_recipent_field,'recipent_form':recipent_form}
    return render(request, 'mains/your_template.html, context)
```

**Note 1** :- You will have to a Recipent Form that i accessed in the view.

**Note 2** :- `model_contains_recipent_field` is the model that contains `recipent field`.

If you will access recipent_form then it'll select recipient's profile page by `user_id` .